Probability supported on $M$
I was trying to understand the statement of a theorem which guarantees the existence of a probability, etc.
Let $X$ is a Banach space and $M\subseteq X$ compact. There exists a probability $\mu$, supported on $M$, such that the function
$$\varphi_{\mu}(z)=\int_{M}\|z-m\|^2 d\mu(m)$$
its minimum at the point.

I would like to understand the definition of probability supported in $M$, any good references to study the subject?

Is this $\varphi_\mu$ function defined in $X$?


$$\varphi_\mu \colon X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

What type of object is $X$? Is it a topological vector space? Something else?

@mathperson314 $X$ is a Banach space.

$\mu$ supported on $M$ means that $\mu(X \setminus M) = 0$; that is, there is zero probability outside of $M$. For instance, the probability measure $\mu(A) = \mathcal{L}(A \cap [0,1])$ (where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lebesgue measure) is supported on $[0,1]$.
You are correct, $\varphi_\mu$ as defined has domain $X$ and codomain the reals (in fact; the nonnegative reals seeing as it is the integral of a nonnegative integrand w.r.t. a positive measure).

In my case, in mathematical terms, what does it mean to have zero probability outside of $M$ ?

@AlphaMaths Remember that a (probability) measure on $X$ is a function which takes in a subset of $X$ and returns the corresponding probability, subject to certain rules. So in this case, I mean that the probability of the outcome being in the complement of $M$ is zero.
